# GNAT GPS debugger-cannot set value to variables

Tags: debugging, ada, gnat-gps

I am not able to set value to any variables in GPS debugger. I am able to print the value or display the value but I am not able to set (change) the value for any of the variables.

Could it be because of building with 'O2' optimizations?

If I right click a variable and check,'view memory at address of variable', there is no specific content, but only '-------' hyphens exist.

Comment: Try building at Og (optimise for debuggability) and find out.

Comment: I tried running, but could not still set value.

Comment: @Brian, Actually `-Og` means to optimise a bit, but retain values for debuggability - but not necessarily past their last use in a subprogram. `-O0` might be better.

Comment: Simon, I tried running with -O0, still could not set value to variables

Comment: do you have any actual data to help us out ? Like : code sample, GPS version, compiler version and compile/link options (eg : the .gpr content)